# Why is $\text{Ric}(g)=0$ a quasi-linear PDE in harmonic coordinates?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, general-relativity, hyperbolic-equations, semi-riemannian-geometry

While studying the dynamics of the Einstein vacuum equations
$$
\text{Ric}(g)=0
$$
for $(M,g)$ unknwon, I've come across the statement that in harmonic coordinates $x^\lambda$ defined by $\Box_g x^\lambda=0$ the principal part (all terms containing second derivaties of $g_{\mu\nu}$) of $\text{Ric}_{\mu\nu}$ is
$$
g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\alpha\partial_\beta g_{\mu\nu}
$$
so that $\text{Ric}_{\mu\nu}=0$ becomes
$$
g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\alpha\partial_\beta g_{\mu\nu} = F(g,\partial g)
$$
which is then quasi-linear.

---

Now I know that
$$
\text{Ric}_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\alpha\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\nu}-\partial_\nu\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\alpha}+\Gamma^\alpha_{\alpha\beta}\Gamma^\beta_{\mu\nu}-\Gamma^\alpha_{\mu\beta}\Gamma^\beta_{\nu\alpha}
$$
and also that in harmonic coordinates $g^{\alpha\beta}\Gamma^\lambda_{\alpha\beta}=0$  which can be seen when writing $\Box_g x^\lambda=0$ in local coordinates.

---

My question is: How does one get from this that the principal part of the Ricci is $g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\alpha\partial_\beta g_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: Use the form of the Christoffel symbols in terms of $g^{-1}$ and $\partial g$

Comment: Just a comment about the terminology: Einstein equations are always quasilinear, in arbitrary coordinates. Quasilinear just means that the equations are linear in the highest order derivatives (e.g. there are no terms like $(\partial\partial g)^{2}$ or other non-linear espressions of $(\partial\partial g$)), which is the case for Einstein's equations. What happens in the harmonic coordinate choice is that the equations become hyperbolic.